# Link 2 points on a map, resulting line must not pass through the land

Tags: c#

I have to do a program for my school to manage ships. 
A part of it involves using a map to create travels: the user has to click on some points fixed by me on the map (I've thought to use a Panel with the map as BGimage) which represent ports.

When i click on the second point I have to show one or more lines on the screen which link these 2 ports, but these lines should not pass through the land, just through the sea.

Here are some examples:

**Wrong**
[image: Wrong]

**Correct**
[image: Correct]

So, could you give me some advice on how to do it?

I don't want the code, just some ideas, if it's possible to do.

Thank you.

Comment: This is too broad. You would have to first find what is water and what is land (by pixel color?). Then you would have to use a path finding algorithm, e.g. A* for finding the quickest path. Then you have to figure out what happens if user clicks on water or how to handle situation when someone clicks on an unreachable place. Your map has limited resolution, so you may want to find more precise, vector map that outlines countries.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm as described on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm and the description on motion planning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning

The idea would be to identify your starting point and your end point. Then follow the example of the motion planning as depicted in the illustration of the algorithm:
Traverse to each valid pixel that moves you closer to the target pixel. Use, for example, the color of the pixel to check whether the pixel is a 'sea' pixel or a 'land' pixel, so you create the motion wave-front to get to the target pixel.
By 'visiting' these pixels you create a graph (store the traversals as nodes as a set of vertices and endges).
Once you 'hit' the target node, use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all I have to use the grid based search: I have understood how it works, but I have no idea on how to apply it to my program.
I have never done something so difficult. Could you help me in any way?